# What is the most natural

Tags: grammar, particle-から

Question:今夜起きたから寝るですか？
What is the most natural?

いいえ、今夜働いてるから起きています
Or
いいえ、今夜働いてるので起きています

Comment: `今夜起きたから寝るですか？` -- This sentence doesn't really make sense. Also, 寝る+ですか is grammatically incorrect. What is it supposed to mean?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Are you going to sleep because you didn't sleep last night?

If this situation is this morning and you stayed up from last night, 昨日起きていたから寝ますか？

Are you going to sleep tomorrow because you are going to stay up all night?

今日寝ないから明日は寝ますか？
今日起きてるから明日は寝ますか？

No I'm not going to sleep because I have to work

いいえ 働いているので起きています。

First sentence depends on the time last night or tonight. But
Your question is のでorから.

In this case, both are correct. But usingので in polite Japanese is trend. Actuallyので means "cause of","due to".

からis "because" . But Japanese usage has changed to useので in every situation. So I assume other Japanese people would answer のでis natural.

If it's a little bit casual conversation, we tend to use 今日 or 今日の夜 instead of 今夜.
今夜sounds like formal.